# firebase security rule setting problem. resource return null value

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Setting rules in firebase.
Here's what I want.

1. Anyone who is logged in can write.
2. Written articles are stored in the collection called story with the values of the author, writing time, content, and uid fields. The document is automatically named because the add function was used in the filter.
3. Currently, all users can read all users' posts.

What I want is to set firebase rules so that I can only see what I wrote.

I've tried many things about the rule setting, but it keeps failing, causing the error below.

> W/Firestore( 4545): (24.4.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(feeds order by -time, -**name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

This is the method you tried.
try 1:

```
rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /story /{storyId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.storyId
  }
 }
}
```

try 2:

```
rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /story /{storyId} {
     allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == storyId
  }
 }
}
```

For your information, when request.auth.uid == request.auth.uid == "uid direct input" instead of request.auth.uid r resource.data.uid, the app ran normally.

Among the fields inside the document, it would be nice if only you could see what you wrote through the uid comparison.

Simply think of it as an individual blog app that shares the same server. The reason why I don't save it locally is to share it with friends through the friend add-on function later.

If there is a better way to compare uid, you can share it with us.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
          .orderBy('time', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final feedDocs = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: feedDocs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
```

Comment: Rules on their own do nothing yet. Please edit your question to show the minimal code which we can run against these rules to reproduce the error.

Comment: Teacher, I'm ignorant because I'm a beginner.  When you modify the rules in the firebase to (request.auth.uid == resource.data.user), null occurs in the emulator. If (snapshot.data == null) was added for null occurrence, and the emulator no longer encounters null errors. However, the data has been received normally and cannot be read. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Can you edit your question to also show a screenshot of a document that you expec the query to return, and indicate where in that screenshot the UID of the user is showing (which is what your security rules check for)?